# Bootstrap maxlength doesn't work in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, maxlength

I'm using Bootstrap Maxlength plugin to show the maximum lenght of a field while the user is inserting text. It works well with input fields and textareas of a page. The problem is that it doesn't work when the input or the textarea field is in a modal dialog.

I have this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input.max-length-field').maxlength({
    limitReachedClass: "label label-danger",
    alwaysShow: true
  });
  $('textarea.max-length-field').maxlength({
    limitReachedClass: "label label-danger",
    alwaysShow: true
  });
});
```

So all inputs and textareas with "max-length-field" class, should display the remaining chars. But when the field is in a modal dialog, it doesn't work.

How can I get this working?

EDIT:

HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<html>
...
<head>...</head>
<body>
...
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            My Field
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="mymodalfield" type="text" maxlength="150" id="idmymodalfield" class="form-control max-length-field" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" name="myModalButton" value="Yes" onclick="...." class="btn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    ...
    <input name="myfield" type="text" maxlength="10" id="idmyfield" class="form-control max-length-field" />
    ...
    </div>
</div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap Maxlength is working well with "myfield" input, but it doesn't appear in "mymodalfield".

Answer (score 0):

> is in a modal dialog, it doesn't work.

maybe your width changes appears before you call modal window? please first of all check this, because in other way it will not work, correctly(it works at your html, as DOM structure you have than modal-callback, and than width changes)

p.s.
can you show me more your code?

Comment: I edited the question with some code. I don't understand what you mean with "width changes".

Answer (score 0):

the problem comes from the Z-index of the modal compared to the z-index of the textarea word counter :

go to bootstrap-maxlength.min.js and change zIndex value to a superior number ( if modal z-index is 1500 then put zIndex as 1520 in the file )

don't forget to clear your cache in your browser
, et voilà!